# Fourier inversion of $f(k) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{k \to -\infty } f(k)=0$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $k \to f(k)$ be a function and define its Fourier transform as
$$
\hat{f} (u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iux} f(x) dx
$$
if $\hat{f} (u)$ is integrable we can get back $f$ by doing the inversion
$$
f(k)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-iux} \hat{f}(u) du
$$
now a source I am reading indicates (if I understand it correctly) that this can be done if and only if 
$$
\lim_{k\to -\infty} f(k) =0
$$
is this true? If so how come?

Comment: The condition you need is that $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are integrable. If $\hat{f}$ is integrable, then the condition $\lim_{|k| \to \infty} f(k) = 0$ follows from the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, but this condition alone is not sufficient (it doesn't even guarantee $f \in L^1$, for instance).

Comment: Either you misunderstood, or misquoted, or the source is incorrect. Why not give a direct quote or reference?

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed misunderstand it. If you like you may make some kind of answer and I will accept since you made me figure it out.